# how to prevent a document getting indexed during full import?

Tags: mongodb, solr, dataimporthandler

I have a mongodb collection which i would like to index on solr using data import handler . But i don't want the documents with foodType(a field in document) as variant to get indexed during full import how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the query to get the documents from the MongoDB.
Then modify that query by adding a filtering condition.
This filter will not retreive the data from mongoDB where the documents has foodType.

e.g

```
db.collection.find({ "fieldToCheck" : { $exists : true, $ne : null } })
```

You can add some conditions as above in your query and restrict the data from being indexed in solr.

In the data-config the query is missing and that is the reason its getting all the documents from mongoDB. If you add the query with correct criteria it will retrive selected documents.

For more on the mongo Query please refer the link below

[MOngoDB reference link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/)

Comment: no i am not using any queries to get documents from mongo db i am using the curl commands  curl http://localhost:8983/solr/food/dataimport?command=full-import for data import is there a way to filter the docs here or in solr schema file

Comment: have you mentioned the foodType in your schema.xml...? then remove it ...it wont be stored as a part of solr document...

Comment: but for your your data-import have you not configured any data-config.xml?

Comment: yes i have a data-config.xml you want me to change anything in the entity

Comment: i can't remove the foodType as i need it desperatley

Comment: but you have mentioned that you dont want the same...its bit confusing ...what exactly you want and you dont want...?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataConfig>
<dataSource name="MyMongo" type="MongoDataSource" database="appdb" />
<document name="import">
 <!-- if query="" then it imports everything -->
     <entity  processor="MongoEntityProcessor"
             query=""
             collection="food"   
             datasource="MyMongo"
             transformer="MongoMapperTransformer" name="sample_entity">

                                        
       </entity>
 </document>
</dataConfig>

Comment: the above is my data config file

Comment: Add the query if you dont want to get any specific document?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89652/discussion-between-aswin-raghavan-and-abhijit-bashetti).